# Middle school algebra query

Tags: linear-algebra

so when I move

```
15 x + 3 y = 2
```

to get `y` alone

```
3 y = 2 - 15 x
```

and then want to move `x` to be on the right can I do this?

```
3 y = -15 x + 2
```

or should it be

```
3 y = 15 x - 2
```

Comment: This seems like a question for [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

With the [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) function you calculate the value of `y`.

The second line of the command is a combination of "texts" and the "desired value". The [`ToStrings`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToStrings.html) function converts the result of a function to a text format.

```
Solve[15 x + 3 y == 2, y] /. Rule -> Set;
"3y" <> " = " <> ToString[3 y]
```

> 3y = 2 - 15 x

Comment: `Inactive[Set]["3y", 3 y]`